# problems with spring data elastic search FindByLocationWithin

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to query a elastic search repository to return data. I'm using the following code

Dao:

```
public interface Dao extends ElasticsearchRepository<Entity, String> {

List<Entity> findByLocationWithin(Point point, Distance  distance);
```

Service:

```
    Point point = new Point(19.41762567,-99.12835121);
    Distance distance = new Distance(0.2,Metrics.KILOMETERS);

    List<Entity> a=dao.findByLocationWithin(point,distance);
```

The problem is with the value Double of Distance, spring data in the class CriteriaFilterProcessor cast the value to int and loses the decimal part.

```
   sb.append((int)distance.getValue());
```

Is there a way to pass decimals?